# Using lighttpd to send requests to TCP socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, webserver, lighttpd, mod-fastcgi

This is my first set up of a webserver, so it's an experimental learning experience.
I had successfully got **lighttpd** using **mod_fastcgi** (https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modfastcgi) working to send a request to a separate process via a **TCP socket**. It sends the request using the FastCGI protocol.

But is there a module or way to send raw data to the TCP socket **without the FastCGI protocol**? Alternatively, if not lighttpd, **is there another lightweight webserver** that does allow sending basic requests to a TCP socket without any extra protocol wrapping around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for lighttpd mod_proxy.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy